# iphone send mail in background when didUpdateToLocation occurs

Tags: iphone

I get working skpsmtpmessage(http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/).
So I can send mail in foreground.

Now I wish to send send a mail by skpsmtpmessage in background when didUpdateLocation occurs.

It works in background, I get latitude and longitude, but when send mail starts It stops at first step:
"C: Attempting to connect to server at: smtp.gmail.com:"

Is it impossible do a networks connection in background?

Answer (score 2):

I solve it.
Put into application information property list this entry:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```