# how to send email in the background of iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email

I want send an email in the background of iphone. Can anybody help me regarding that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827014/iphone-sdk-send-email-in-background-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at following URLs;

[iphone send mail in background when didUpdateToLocation occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777611/iphone-send-mail-in-background-when-didupdatetolocation-occurs)

[Article:](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-in-app-email/)

[Example:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MailComposer/Introduction/Intro.html)

I think, it will help you...